# como terminar o liberar file.txt al terminar de llenarlo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Con este metodo cargo de datos un file txt pero no estoy seguro si con el .Dispose se libera el txt para que sea utilizado por otro sistema y no le marque que aun esta siendo utilizado.

```html
  public static void regText(string cadena)
        {
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(@"\\server\carpeta\", "file.txt"), append: true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", cadena));
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                    writer.Dispose();
            
                }
}
```

Comment: para que el archivo sea liberado, solo tenes que cerrarlo con Close, Dispose lo limpia de la memoria

Answer (score 2):

Segun la documentacion sobre [`StreamWriter#Dispose()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.dispose?view=netcore-3.1#comentarios):

> Hace que los datos en búfer se escriban en la secuencia subyacente,
> libera los recursos no administrados que usa `StreamWriter` y, de
> forma opcional, los recursos administrados.

Asi que es seguro afirmar que también se habilitara el archivo para que otro proceso lo pueda utilizar.

Y como bono, ejecutando el metodo `Dispose` tambien ejecuta el metodo `Close()` del `StreaWriter`.

Ten encuenta que no es necesario llamar el metodo `.Dispose()`, `Close()` y `Flush` manualmente si el objecto ya esta dentro de un block `using`, ya que `using` ejecuta automaticamente el metodo `Dispose()` al terminar el bloque de codigo y [este metodo libera todos esos recursos](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,236):

```
public static void regText(string cadena) 
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(@"\\server\carpeta\", "file.txt"), append: true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", cadena));
    }
}
```